# Finding a function/differential equation from a 2nd order recurrence relation

Tags: difference-equations

Consider the following 2nd order recurrence relation:

$$A_{1}=1,\; A_{2}=z$$

$$A_{n+2}(z)=(b_n+z)A_{n+1}(z)+a_nA_{n}(z),\; n=1,2,3,...$$

where,

$$b_n=n\left(n+m+\frac{1}{2}\right),\; a_n=k^2n\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $k\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R},m \in \mathbb{Z}$ are constants

What I want to find is $$f(z) \equiv \lim_{n \to \infty}A_n(z)$$

This will be an infinite series. I want to find the function $f(z)$ either in explicit form or a solution to a differential equation.

Naive attempt:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
sol[z_]:= RSolveValue[{A[n + 2] == (n (n + m + 1/2) + z) A[n + 1] + 
     k^2 n (n - 1/2) A[n], A[1] == 1, A[2] == z}, A[n], n]
```

This gives a `DifferenceRoot` object that I am not able to make much use of.

**Edit 1:**

As finding explicit $f(z)$ might be too much to ask for, I will be happy to know just  how to efficiently determine the zeros of $f(z)$ for a fixed $k$(say $k=1$) and $m$ going from $m=0,\pm 1,\pm2,...,\pm10$ of $f(z)$ with $|z|<500$.

**Edit 2:**

As numerical estimation seems to be the only way out for now, I have opened a new question that is closer to my eventual goal: [Zeros of a rational fraction sequence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174554/zeros-of-a-rational-fraction-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1)
This post shall be updated if some analytic way is found.

Comment: This is a rather non-trivial problem. Do you have any reason to expect an analytic solution exists at all? I believe this question should be asked on math.SE first; and here only if the solution is confirmed to exist and be expressible in closed-form in terms of known functions.

Comment: If `k=0` then `f[z]=Infinty or -Infinity` for all $z$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I have asked similar questions on both MSE and Math Overflow, but of no avail.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk k is strictly non-zero in my case.

Comment: @Subho95 well, if mathematicians cannot solve this problem, it's unlikely you'll find a solution here. Are you interested in a numerical approach? Did you try to do it yourself? A preliminary analysis suggests that $A_n(z)$ diverges as $n\to\infty$ for generic values of $k,m$. Is there any constraint on these parameters?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Well, I am ultimately interested in the zeros of this function when it converges. I understand that for generic values of $k$ or $m$ it may diverge. Even so I want to express it as a composition of elementary functions that do diverge at generic points except some that I am ultimately interested in.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform $m$ is an integer and $k$ can be any real number. And I have no other constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Only a numerical approximation:

**EDITED:**

```
f[z_, m_, k_, inf_] := Last@RecurrenceTable[{A[n + 2] == (n (n + m + 1/2) + z) A[n + 1] + 
k^2 n (n - 1/2) A[n], A[1] == 1, A[2] == z}, A[n], {n, 1, inf}];

tab=Table[{m, z /. NSolve[f[z, m, 1, 20] == 0 && RealAbs[z] < 500, z, 
Reals]}, {m, -10, 10, 1}];(* Assume k=1 and inf=20 !!! *)
```

Visualisation on plots:

```
Show[ListPlot /@ (Tuples[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}] & /@ tab), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Or:**

```
 Show[ListPlot /@ (Tuples[{#[[2]], {#[[1]]}}] & /@ tab), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

for: `k=10`,`inf=25`,`m` in range `{-20,20}` we see a patterns.

[image]

Comment: This is fine. This is kind of expected as this function will behave nicely only at select values of z in the large n limit. I am looking for the zeros ultimately as I mentioned in the comment earlier.

Comment: The zeros should ultimately converge which is what is happening.

Comment: I was trying to visualize by `Show[ListPlot /@ (Tuples[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}] & /@ <output of Table>)]`, but the positive axis gets cut off. Suggestions for fix?

Comment: @Subho95. I edited my answer.

Comment: I have opened a related question today: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174554/zeros-of-a-rational-fraction-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1